# How to place text in a specific location within a TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to place elements of an Array (Strings) within a TEXTAREA.

The background is seen as a lined notebook, so each element in the array (a name string) must be located nicely between the lines. 
Unfortunately, I can't seem to define the location using styling (using JS) in the TEXTAREA. I tried using:

```
textBox.style.top = '76pt';
```

but that doesn't work. It is stock on the top.

Using **textBox.style.top** is no good cause then the Textarea box itself moves - as well applying:  **textBox.style.position = 'absolute'** or **'relative'**.

If you look at my code, you'll see the following lines:

`var points = 76;
textBox.style.top = String(point) + 'pt'; 
points = points + 35;`

that's because I want to automatize this pattern to be in the exact position between the lines regardless to the array's length.

The only way I managed to variate the location is using a new line ('\n') but that's not doing the right job (see the snippet version).

here is the simplified code:

```css
#layout {
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
left: 225px;
width:  800px;
height: 370px;
background-color: white;  
padding-left: 1px;
max-width:100%;
}

textarea {
width:  800px;
height: 370px;
resize: none;
font-size: 45px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
background: url(https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-47327da6ae3e0b3727a9b9a7ea7f1adb?convert_to_webp=true);
}

#in_box{
position: absolute;
top: 76pt;
right: 10pt;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body> 
  <div id="layout">
  <textarea maxlength="200" readonly="readonly" id="myText" dir="auto" name="outtest" class = "fetchBox"></textarea> 
  <span id="in_box" class="fetch" name="testOutput"></span>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
<script>
var textBox = document.getElementById('myText');
var myArr = ['Sparrow', 'Blackbird','Dove'];
var points = 76;
if(myArr.constructor === Array) {
 for(i=0; i < myArr.length; ++i) {
 textBox.value += '\n'+myArr[i]+'\n';
 textBox.style.fontSize = "30px";
 textBox.style.top = String(points) + 'pt';
 points = points + 35;
 }
}
</script>
```

I would very much appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `line-height:22px;`to your CSS in your textarea section, it should make the text line up.

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't place content this way INSIDE of a textarea element as the interior is nothing more than a text field.  Instead, you should look to using another content container that does allow for its interior to be styled, like a div.

Comment: I tried to change the textarea tag to div as you said. Though the text output is not shown..